# how Remove the white background below the bottom Nav bar flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

hello how i can Remove the white background below the bottom Nav bar?
The white background appears below it, and I want it to be transparent

[white background below the bottom nav bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGNqM.png)

```
return GetBuilder<MainPageController>(
  builder: (controller) => Scaffold(
    extendBody: true,
    bottomNavigationBar: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
        child: BottomAppBar(
          height: 90,
          color: AppColor.buttononbording,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: List.generate(
              controller.listPage.length,
              (index) {
                bool isCenterButton = index == 2;
                return ButtonBottomAppbarWidget(
                  sizeicon: isCenterButton ? 30 : 20,
                  padding: isCenterButton ? 10 : 2,
                  text: isCenterButton
                      ? null
                      : controller.namescreen[index]["title"],
                  icon: controller.namescreen[index]["icon"],
                  onPressed: () {
                    controller.changePage(index);
                  },
                  active: isCenterButton
                      ? false
                      : controller.currentpage == index,
                  center: isCenterButton ? Colors.blue : Colors.transparent,
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    body: controller.listPage.elementAt(controller.currentpage),
  ),
);
```

}
}

Comment: It's not from the nav bar, it's from the body

Answer (score 0):

That "white background" is actually the body of your `Scaffold` which has been extended by setting `extendBody: true`. This is the expected behavior as indicated in the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/extendBody.html).

If you set that flag to `extendBody: false` you will have the transparency you are looking for, and it will show instead the [background color of the scaffold](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/backgroundColor.html).